# Can't synthesize property named 'data'

Tags: xcode, cocoa

I get an undeclared error for property _data when I declare the following property in my class (derived from NSObject).

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableData *data;
```

I can rename `data` to anything and else and synthesis of the ivar and direct access works as expected.  Is _data reserved in some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This had nothing to do with the name of the ivar and everything to do with declaring accessors for it and using auto-synthesis.